# dynamic memory struct: free() failed w/ invalid size

Tags: c, struct, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a C program that allocates memory for a structure and then free it. However, when I try to free the char array inside the struct, I get invalid size/pointer error. I am sure the structure is working fine because I checked by print out the context inside the structure.

```
typedef struct
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    int index;
    char * atom_name;
} atom;

int main(void)
{
int i;
atom * PMI = allocateatom(1000); 

/* some operation that reads in information and stores inside PMI */

// Then frees the memory

char buffer[500] = "";
for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
{   
    strcpy(buffer, PMI[i].atom_name);
    printf("%d %s\n", i, buffer);
   // free(PMI[i].atom_name);
}
free(PMI[0].atom_name);
free(PMI[1].atom_name);

return 0;
}

atom * allocateatom(int num)
{
   atom * target = malloc(num * sizeof(atom));
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<num; i++)
       target[i].atom_name = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));

   return target;
}
```

The result is: if I comment out the two free commands, I got all atom_name print out and exit without error. If I just free(PMI[0].atom_name), the program works fine as well. However as soon as I start to free PMI[1].atom_name, the program crashes with seg fault: invalid size or invalid pointer if I use free(&PMI[i].atom_name)

```
 #2  0x00007ffff7a87e14 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b96668 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
 #3  0x00007ffff7a940ee in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimized out>, str=0x7ffff7b92771 "free(): invalid size", action=1) at malloc.c:4996
 #4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I missed that line. It is defined in my code actually. Also that print block is just for checking the allocation. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also I want to ask very dumb question (searched online but not sure if I understand it right). In the struct define block, if I define atom_name as " char atom_name[5]" instead of "char * atom_name", then I don't have to dynamically allocate memory for it. But the variable itself, atom_name is only a pointer in both case right? Just one to stack memory another to heap memory? Can I use strcpy on both of them?

Comment: If you define it as `char atom_name[5];`, it is going to be an array. Like all arrays, it will decay to a pointer in most usages but it will still be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have allocated memory for `atom_name`. However, you have not set the values to anything sensible.

When you use

```
strcpy(buffer, PMI[i].atom_name);
```

you are running into undefined behavior since `PMI[i].atom_name` hasn't been set to be a null terminated string.

If you change the lines:

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++)
   target[i].atom_name = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
```

to

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++)
{
   target[i].atom_name = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(target[i].atom_name, "test");
}
```

you'll get sane behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Actually I have some sensible string copied from a file and stored in atom_name. (I skipped that part of code by /* some operation that reads in information and stores inside PMI */). But what I did is:  fgets(buffer, 500, FILE); sscanf(buffer, "%s", mytext); PMI[i].atom_name = mytext. Oh I see what stupid thing I did. Is that because I just copied pointer but not the actual value to atom_name?

Comment: That's why we prefer to see an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When you dole out bits and pieces of information, it's almost impossible to tell where the problem is.

Comment: My apologies. I thought hide some unnecessary code will help others to get the key idea quicker. Guess never know what's not necessary. May I follow up a bit? Although doing atom_name = mytext only copies the pointer,  the memory for atom_name has been allocated. So free() should be deleting some memory right? Or this is another undefined situation in C? Sorry I haven't been coding for a while so all my questions look quite naive.

Comment: @CrazyFrog, it's not clear to me how and whether you were able to resolve your problem.

Comment: @R Sahu, I use strcpy to assign mytext to atom_name instead of just copying over the pointer. And it solves the problem.